# Key Vault Reference Limit

Tags: azure, key, azure-keyvault

While developing an ARM template to deploy multiple app services and want to use the key vault to host multiple secret, and we need to include 110 references in the template.

While doing a POC, there is an error message:

> The deployment has specified too many Key Vault parameter references. 
>   The maximum of Key Vault parameter references is '30'

Is it possible to go beyond 30?

Comment: did you try to work around using nested deployments? i believe that should be possible. but in any case, this approach looks flawed

Comment: he is not talking about any sdk or rest call. you reading his question or not? @JoeyCai

Comment: Please, why is it looking flawed @4c74356b41

Comment: 110 references to kv? that seems unmanageable. you need to split it and\or rework it completely

Comment: Okay thanks. So the error still persists after trying nested developments, is there a need to go with the linked template route to bypass the issue?

Comment: In a micro services architecture, a system using more than 30 secrets is not at all surprising.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Key Vault parameter reference limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602558/azure-key-vault-parameter-reference-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Your first option should be to consider why you need so many secrets and how you can come up with a better strategy.

Failing that, on the quick and dirty, you can wrap multiple secrets in the a string.

E.g.:

> MySecret: value1|value2|value3|value4|value5

They you can use the ARM Template functions to pull out the value you need.

Look in to the [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#array) and [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#split) functions.

Hopefully you can keep related secrets together and organise them neatly.